# Implicit conversion operator for templated types not automatically determined

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I have a templated class `thing` with an implicit conversion operator, like follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

template <typename T>
struct thing
{
    T t;

    operator const T&() const 
    { 
        return t;
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct B 
{
    T t;
};

void fun(const int&) {
    printf("int\n");
}

template <typename T>
void fun(const B<T>&) {
    printf("B<T>\n");
}

int main()
{
    thing<int> a;
    fun(a);

    thing<B<int>> b;
    fun(b);

    return 0;
}
```

Calling `fun(const int&)` with a `thing<int>`, the compiler is able to figure out to invoke the implicit conversion operator in order to pass the `const T&` (in this case `const int&`) to `fun(const int&)`.

However, for a `thing<B<int>>`, the compiler can not figure out that I expect `fun(const B<T>&)` to be invoked.

How can I help the compiler figuring this out **without** casting `b` to `const B<int>&` explicitely (using `static_cast<const B<int>&>(b)` for instance)?

My concrete usage scenario is similar to the code provided with the constraints that I am using `B` with ~10 different types `T`, i.e. not arbitrary many different `T`s. If I have to create ~10 template specializations, so be it. However, I don't exactly know how to best overload `struct B` in that case. But maybe I am on the wrong track - do simpler/more elegant solutions exist, maybe?

Comment: You can't basically, that's not how templates work. They don't do conversions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Implicit_conversions) doesn't consider implicit conversion.

> Type deduction does not consider implicit conversions (other than type adjustments listed above): that's the job for [overload resolution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution), which happens later.

Then given `fun(b);`, the template `fun` can't be invoked because `T` can't be deduced.

You can specify the template argument explicitly, then overload resolution and implicit conversion would work fine.

```
fun<int>(b);
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/BWFAfGkCi5jwJoGb)

Answer (score 3):

> How can I help the compiler figuring this out without casting `b` to `const B<int>&`?

You can't.  Templates do not do any implicit conversion.  They deduce the type of the parameter and that is the type they use.

One thing you can do is add a get function to your wrapper like

```
template <typename T>
struct thing
{
    T t;

    operator const T&() const 
    { 
        return t;
    }
    const T& get() const 
    { 
        return t; 
    }
};
```

and then you can call `fun` like

```
fun(b.get());
```

Comment: So, I can't partially specialize on `B` or something like that? But I could create 10 overloads to `fun()`, right?

Comment: @j00hi You can't partially specialize functions.  You could add 10 concrete function overloads.